# How to run web project in VS Code using terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I watched a video on YouTube and the creator created a simple JavaScript project. After that he just ran it in the terminal of VS Code.

I searched about this on YouTube and Google but I can't understand it.

How do I run my JavaScript project using the terminal in VS Code?

Comment: Most modern solutions for local web development assume you have [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) available on your system and rely on it. I can't be sure, as you have provided no details about your environment, but there's a high chance that's what you're missing. Most likely, you'll find tutorials on how to run a node based web server on local on whatever machine you happen to be.

Comment: 1) [install node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/); 2) [get started](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)

Answer (score 3):

You should get help from Node.js ecosystem!

1. Install Node.js LTS version from official website! ([node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/))
2. Install live-server package([live-server website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)) globally
3. Go to the directory where the project is.

   ~ cd path/to/project
4. Then just run

   ~ live-server

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodejs, but you can't use some javascript keywords and methods which run on the browser like `document` `addEventListener` (but we have `on` method). Because node is built for server-side applications, there is no `document` on the server.

If you are working on a frontend application, there are many packages you can use, like

- serve (`npm install -g serve`)
- live server (`npm install -g live-server`)
- webpack